# How can I convert RGB to Lab?

Tags: perl, api, imagemagick

I have RGB values of downscaled pictures in my database and would like to use imagemagick to take care of the conversion to [Lab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space). But I have not been able to find code samples for this.

How can i convert RGB color values to Lab using the Perl Imagemagick API? Is this even possible?

Comment: I would like to know why this question seems to be no real question? I clearly defined what i want.

Comment: Because they might not be available on some customer installations. I was searching for a solution without the usage of another package. We are using imagemagick for many tasks. I was interessted to get to know if there would be a way to use the perl imagemagick API for this.

Comment: @pmakholm: That is a ridiculous basis for closing a question. The OP didn't even say he wouldn't accept an alternative module

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't work with ImageMagick - there's a CPAN module for this and my first little try to search for `RGB Lab` gave me [Graphics::ColorObject](http://p3rl.org/Graphics%3a%3aColorObject).

```
my $color = Graphics::ColorObject->new_RGB([0.5, 0.42, 0.17]);
my ($L, $a, $b) = @{ $color->as_Lab() };
```

Comment: well, this is exactly a package which is not available on all systems where the code should run (but +1 for a working approach)

Comment: @Thariama It isn't installed by default. but it doesn't have very many [bugs](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Graphics-ColorObject) considering it hasn't been updated since 2005. Also it is pure Perl, so you shouldn't have any difficulty installing it. ( Even if you have to copy it into your project directory.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but it seems like there is no way to use the Perl imagemagick API for this.
Instead i am using some functions from [Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?parent=68072;node_id=3333) (user unknown):

```
# I do not do the linear approximation for $u/$un <= 0.008859
sub RGB2Lab {
  my ($red, $green, $blue) = @_;

  my ($x, $y, $z)    = _RGB2XYZitu($red, $green, $blue);
  my ($xn, $yn, $zn) = _RGB2XYZitu(1,1,1);
  my $fx = _cuberoot($x/$xn);
  my $fy = _cuberoot($y/$yn);  
  my $fz = _cuberoot($z/$zn);

  return ( 116*$fy-16, 500*($fx - $fy), 200*($fy - $fz) );

}

sub Lab2RGB {
  my ($L, $a, $b) = @_;
  my ($xn, $yn, $zn) = _RGB2XYZitu(1,1,1); 

  my $fL = _cube(($L+16)/116);
  my $fa = _cube($a/500);
  my $fb = _cube($b/200);

  my $y = _cube( ($L+16)/116) * $yn;
  my $x = _cube( ($L+16)/116 + $a/500 ) * $xn;
  my $z = _cube( ($L+16)/116 - $b/200 ) * $zn;

  return _XYZitu2RGB($x, $y, $z);

}

sub _RGB2XYZitu {
  my ($r, $g, $b) = @_;
  return ( 
    0.431*$r + 0.342*$g + 0.178*$b,
    0.222*$r + 0.707*$g + 0.071*$b,
    0.020*$r + 0.130*$g + 0.939*$b 
  );
}

sub _XYZitu2RGB {
  my ($x, $y, $z) = @_;

  return  map { $_ > 1 ? 1 : $_ } (
    3.063*$x - 1.393*$y - 0.476*$z,
   -0.969*$x + 1.876*$y + 0.042*$z,
    0.068*$x - 0.229*$y + 1.069*$z 
  );

}

sub _cuberoot {
  my $x = shift;  
  return 0 if $x == 0;
  my $sign = ($x < 0) ? -1 : 1;
  $x *= $sign;
  return $sign * exp( log($x)/3.0 );  
}

sub _cube {
  my $x = shift;
  return 0 if $x == 0;
  my $sign = ($x < 0) ? -1 : 1;
  $x *= $sign;
  return $sign * exp( 3 * log($x) );
}
```